# Searching for a minimum cycle in a graph containing a set of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, traveling-salesman, undirected-graph

If i have an undirected weighted graph G = (V, e) and a set of nodes P, how do i find the minimum cycle containing all the nodes in P?

I have a large graph G and a set of nodes P based on user input. After I get the user input i want to find the shortest path on G containing all the nodes in P.

There is a constant starting/ending node which will always be located at P[0].

I think this could be some modification of the traveling salesmen problem, which finds the shortest path including all vertices.

Comment: Can weights be negative?

Comment: @Mushroomator No they cannot be

Comment: Do you want min-cycle (as in heading) or min edges to have all nodes (as in description)? If it is latter, its called `minimum-spanning tree` which you can look-up easily, standard algo

Comment: @vish4071 i want the min-cycle as said in the header, sorry for the confusion. Most of the edges have similar weight, so i do not think the two solutions would be too different. Is there an easily accessible MST algorithm that will work for what i want? I do not want to connect all the nodes, only the required ones, as indicated by being in P[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two propositions, one is based on a greedy algorithm that *might* give you *a* path and another that *should* give you the best path if one exists.

### Greedy solution

1. Set the starting node `p_start = P[0]`
2. set the Graph `G(v,e)`with nodes `v` and edges `e`
3. From the stating node `p_start`, run [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) until all the nodes in the set `P` are reached
4. Save the shortest path out af all the possible paths from `p_start` to any of the other nodes in the set `p`. Let us note the shortest path as the path from `p_start` to the node `P[ii]`
5. Remove `P[ii]` from the set `P` and remove the edges from `e`
6. Return to step 3. until the set `p` is empty

### Explenation

As I said, this solution is greedy as it saves the shorest path from the start to any of the candidate nodes in the set `P`. This solution might not reutrn an answer even though an answer might exist since the solution might be taking a little longer path at certain points to successfully complete the cycle.

### Solution suggestion

Now that we put the foundations, we can move to the solution I would suggest. This problem can be looked at a [Self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) problem. I have written an implementation for a solution to finding all possible paths in the self avoiding problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529162/how-to-find-all-possible-unique-paths-in-a-grid/71598567#71598567), but this is more problematic. For small number of nodes, you could run the solution in the attached which is to compute all possible paths and then choose the best one out of all the paths passing at all the nodes in `P`. For large graphs however, I would suggest the following adaptation:

1. Set the starting node `p_start = P[0]`, remove `P[0]` from the set
2. set the Graph `G(v,e)`with nodes `v` and edges `e`
3. set starting path to empty list `path = []`
4. Set `state_stack` to empty list `[]`
5. From `p_start`, run Dijkstra's algorithm to the rest of the nodes in set 'P'
6. For `ii` in length('P'):

   6.1. Note `e_ii` to be the edges chosen to connect `p_start` to `P[ii]`

   6.2. Note `P_ii` to be the set `P` without `P[ii]`

   6.3. Create a new tuple `(P[ii], G(v, e\e_ii), P_ii, path + e_ii)` and add to `state_stack` (New starting state, new graph, new must pass set, taken path so far)
7. Pop another state from `state_line`: `new_state = state_stack.pop()`
8. Set `p_start = new_state[0]` ; `G = new_state[1]` ; `P = new_state[2]`
9. Go back to step 5. until `state_stack` will be empty
10. Choose the best accumulated path

### Explenation

This procedure will compute the shortest path using Dijkstra's. This path will be saved and from each of the destinations, a new path will be computed to all remaining destinations etc. This algorithm will grow factorially by the size of the initial set `P` but will return the best solution if such a solution exists since it computes all possible permutations of visits in the set `P` before choosing the best permutation and returning it.

Comment: Thanks for the response man i really appreciate it! I will look into both of these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're referring to is a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). It calculates the minimum total edge weight in order to connect every vertex in the graph. There are two main algorithms to implement a MST (minimum spanning tree. One is [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), and one is [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). I suggest you look into both these solutions, however in your question you mentioned that you have an initial starting vertex P[0], in which case I would recommend you looking into Prim's algorithm.

Comment: I am not looking to connect every node, I am looking for a (minimum?) weight cycle that has to go through certain nodes, the ones located in P[]. I will add an edit tomorrow morning with some more context of that I’m trying to do :).